# Perl matching text using recursions spanning multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl, regex-recursion

In the text below, I am trying to match `\rem{lp}{some text with nested curly braces}`. The [regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/dAmXcV/1) works for the regex:

```
([^\s]*\s*)\\rem\{(?:lp|db)\}(\{((?>[^{}]|\n|(?2))*)\})(\s?[^\s]*)
```

I would like it to work in perl as well:

```
/([^\s]*\s*)\\rem\{(?:lp|db)\}(\{((?>[^{}]|\n|(?2))*)\})(\s?[^\s]*)/g
```

However, the perl version fails (the file `text.txt` containes the text below). It seems to be due to the line breaks. How do I correct that (I also tried adding `m` modifier without help?

```
perl -ne 'while(/([^\s]*\s*)\\rem\{(?:lp|db)\}(\{((?>[^{}]|\n|(?2))*)\})(\s?[^\s]*)/g){print ++$a."$&\n";}' test.txt
```

`test.txt`

```
Some text etc word\rem{lp}{ more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps}.

\rem{lp}{ more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps 
where  more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps from 
who  more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps.}

\rem{lp}{ more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps. 
 more text {\ce{O2}} further text {\ce{H2O}} . some other text the $m = 48$ ({\ce{O2}}) ps.}

\subsection{other}
Our bla bla bla
```

Comment: Make sure the file has `LF` newlines, not `CRLF`. Use `dos2unix` to fix it if necessary.

Comment: Or change the regex to use `\r?\n` in place of `\n`.

Comment: @Barmar that does not help. Also note that the regex101 version works perfectly fine without `\n` and I do not think it is needed because it is included in the `[^{}]` set, it was just one of my desperate attempts.

Comment: Within `{some text with nested curly braces}` of `\rem{lp}{some text with nested curly braces}` in your example there are what I would count as two levels of nested braces (e.g., `{\ce{O2}}`). Is that always the case or might the levels of nesting be smaller or larger?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this. Perl does not slurp in one liners, so the `while` portion reads still line by line. To get around that, one has to run

```
perl -0777 -ne 'while(/([^\s]*\s*)\\rem\{(?:lp|db)\}(\{((?>[^{}]|\n|(?2))*)\})(\s?[^\s]*)/g){print ++$a."$&\n";}' test.txt
```